# Convert Dataset to ListItem

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert the DATASET into LISTITEM using C#.NET or is there any way that i can read the xmlfile using the xmltextreader and upload that data into the list item?

Comment: Too vague, you need to clarify what your trying to do and show the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

the actual implementation of this will vary as your question is relatively vague.

You could simply iterate through the DataRows in your DataSet:

```
foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
```

You could use an XMLDocument and use Linq-to-Xml to do the same thing.  Post code if you're having issues.